# connect to mysql database using php on different port

Tags: php, mysql, apache, database-connection

my connection string is:

```
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could Not Connect to DB: ".mysql_error());
```

but on my computer i have installed IIS server first so localhost:80 is reserved by it so I changed my port to 8080 changing httpd.conf file in apache folder.

Now what should I change in connection string to connect to my database.
I am using XAMPP .

should I tried writing these:
1:

```
  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost:8080", "root", "") or  die("Could Not Connect to DB: ".mysql_error());
```

2:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost,8080", "root", "") or    die("Could Not Connect to DB: ".mysql_error());
```

But Not working Help please.
Thank You

Comment: **Stop** using deprcated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`instead.

Comment: You should use mysqli_ instead mysql_

Comment: You don't have to change anything, actually. The connection to your mysql server is a connection to the port mysql is listening on. That has _nothing_ to do with the port your http server listens on.

Comment: you have to change nothing. The Standard mysql port is 3306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default port number which Mysql server uses is 3306
Web servers default port is 80

Web server and Mysql server are independent.

Do not change your api to connect to your mysql